# If the Lebesgue integral of a strictly positive function is zero...

Tags: lebesgue-integral

If the Lebesgue integral (over a set A) of a strictly positive function is zero, it means that the Lebesgue measure of A is zero?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for my English :D

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Now it's your turn. Hint: Show that $\{x\in A\colon f(x)>1/n\}$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 5):

Since $f \chi_A \ge 0$ you can use Chebyshev's inequality. For any $\epsilon > 0$ you have $$\mu(\{f \chi_A > \epsilon\}) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int f \chi_A \, d\mu = 0.$$
Take the union over a sequence $\epsilon_k \searrow 0$ to obtain $\mu(\{f \chi_A > 0\}) = 0$.
Finally note
$$x \in A \implies f(x) \chi_A(x) > 0 \implies x \in \{f \chi_A > 0\}$$
so that $A \subset \{f \chi_A > 0\}$. Thus $\mu(A) = 0$.

Comment: I would call that [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) (Markov was a student of Chebyshev and Chebyshev may have found it first)